# Are there any good Tapestry 5 components for implementing tabs/ tabbed navigation?

Tags: java, tapestry

Also, if there are, which would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any mature components if that's what you were looking for.  There is [this project](http://code.google.com/p/redijedi-t5-components/) which is now discontinued.

There is however, a good guide to creating a tab panel here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToCreateATabPanel

And a blog post on how that first project was created here:

http://blog.torr.redijedi.com/2007/08/t5-tab-component.html

Answer (score 1):

Also look at:
http://www.chenillekit.org/chenillekit-tapestry/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a mature component now. You should definitely take a look at https://kawwa.atosworldline.com/component/tabs and the Kawwa components in general.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created an AJAX based TabGroup component for use with the twitter-bootstrap CSS.

Usage:

```
<t:stitch.tabGroup active="fruitTab">
    <t:stitch.tab label="Apples">${applesContent}</t:stitch.tab>
    <t:stitch.tab label="Oranges">${orangesContent}</t:stitch.tab>
    <t:stitch.tab label="Pears">${pearsContent}</t:stitch.tab>
</t:stitch.tabGroup>
```

Code/Demo:

- http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/tabgroupdemo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any mature components too (for what I saw).

You can use some dedicated DHTML components, like [DHTMLX](http://dhtmlx.com/).

We use it a lot in our project for our customers, and it's really great !